# Django RF update_or_create

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update or create the following model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    canMakeEvent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

with the serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

and view:

```
def post(self, request):
    answer, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
    user=request.user, canMakeEvent = request.data['canMakeEvent'])
    return Response()
```

I understand the response isn't correct but the code to update_or_create is what I'm worried about primarily. The console outputs the following:

**UNIQUE constraint failed: event_profile.user_id**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [`defaults`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create) argument to perform search only by user_id not by combination of (user_id, canMakeEdit):

```
answer, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
user=request.user, defaults={'canMakeEvent': request.data['canMakeEvent']})
```

This will allow to update existing profile of selected user if it exists or create new otherwise.